# JS Возможен ли fetch БЕЗ await?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Возможно ли записать [fetch запрос](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch) без `await` ?

```
function getData() {
        let response = fetch('https://api1.test.com/');
        if (!response.ok) {
            const message = `An error has occured: ${response.status}`;
            //throw new Error(message);
        }
        let result = await response.json(); /// Если убрать await получаем response.json is not a function
        return  result
    }
```

Если не нужна асинхронность, если необходимо что б функция выполнялась в тот момент когда её вызывают, игнорирую другие задачи.

Comment: Вы просто не понимаете что вам нужно.... во первых await можно  писать только если функция сама помечена как async......... во-вторых в чём проблема писать axync await? с помощью неё можно спокойно так же дождаться ответа и потом выполнять другие строки кода если надо

Comment: Используйте промисы.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Если у данной конструкции нету такой возможности, и fetch не работает без async, так и надо указать. (Если знаете наверняка, желательно с примерами)

Comment: @Simon Можно подробнее ? Как без асинхронности делать запросы ?

Comment: Просто зачем делать такую бессмысленность? Вы же понимаете, что неасинхронность заблокирует UI на время запроса и пользователь никуда не сможет ткнуть и через 3-4 секунды подумает, что приложение зависло и закроет его нафиг? Или вам такое поведение пользователя и нужно?  ....ЗЫ: у fetch нет синхронности....потому что разрабы понимают, что это глупая вещь, никому не нужна

Comment: @Simon промисы - это тот же async/await, в нём нет никакой синхронности

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я просто не совсем уверен что здесь в принципе вопрос именно в синхронности (хотя вроде как в теле вопроса это и описано), так как в определенной мере это имеет отношение к другому вопросу и возможно из-за этого есть определенное недопонимание.

Comment: @Simon я тоже не уверен, поэтому жду овтет ТС по поводу зависания UI. А если дело в его не понимании смысла "синхронный/асинхронный"  то опять же, тот же async/await вполне решает проблему, просто ТС ищет костыль.... зачем-то

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Просто он использовал async/await и ему оставили комментарий вида: "Зачем там асинхронный запрос? Смысла в нём ноль. Всё равно надо ждать ответа, прежде чем отправлять ajax. Уберите асинхронность.". С этого все и началось. Хотя там просто нужен запрос дабы потом передать аяксом JSON ответ на бек.

Comment: @Simon значит тот, кто так написал - полный идиот)) и если это препод на курсах - то бежать надо от такого))

Comment: скорей всего человеку нужен локер на весь экран, пока выполняется запрос

Comment: У меня получение большого json (3.5Мб) и запись его в БД. Пока запрос не пришел, php не должен писать ничего в БД.... а он пишет пустоту. Поскольку асинхронный запрос не успевает выдать ответ а php уже пишет его в Базу.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 это значит что вы делаете какую-то дичь. и, как я уже описал, async/await вполне позволяет сделать выполнение строчек кода одной за другой. Так что вам нужно  не избавляться от асинхронности, а правильно скомпоновать получение данных и его запись (ну и можно повесить "идёт загрузка", как написали выше). Для этого скорее всего надо новый вопрос создать и описать полноценно что где и предоставив полный код. Сейчас это просто требования решить проблему каким-то костылём......особенно когда оно повесит UI минут на 5 - совсем отличненько будет. Пользователи будут рады такому решению